# DALEIF1 margin top

Tags: header-footer, memoir

I am new guy on texstackexchange...
I am using the daleif1 theme for my heading :

```
 \documentclass{memoir}
    \usepackage{color,calc,graphicx,soul,fourier}
    \definecolor{nicered}{rgb}{.647,.129,.149}
    \makeatletter
    \newlength\dlf@normtxtw
    \setlength\dlf@normtxtw{\textwidth}
    \def\myhelvetfont{\def\sfdefault{mdput}}
    \newsavebox{\feline@chapter}
    \newcommand\feline@chapter@marker[1][4cm]{%
      \sbox\feline@chapter{%
        \resizebox{!}{#1}{\fboxsep=1pt%
          \colorbox{nicered}{\color{white}\bfseries\sffamily\thechapter}%
        }}%
      \rotatebox{90}{%
        \resizebox{%
          \heightof{\usebox{\feline@chapter}}+\depthof{\usebox{\feline@chapter}}}%
        {!}{\scshape\so\@chapapp}}\quad%
      \raisebox{\depthof{\usebox{\feline@chapter}}}{\usebox{\feline@chapter}}%
    }
    \newcommand\feline@chm[1][4cm]{%
      \sbox\feline@chapter{\feline@chapter@marker[#1]}%
      \makebox[0pt][l]{% aka \rlap
        \makebox[1cm][r]{\usebox\feline@chapter}%
      }}
    \makechapterstyle{daleif1}{
      \renewcommand\chapnamefont{\normalfont\Large\scshape\raggedleft\so}
      \renewcommand\chaptitlefont{\normalfont\huge\bfseries\scshape\color{nicered}}
      \renewcommand\chapternamenum{}
      \renewcommand\printchaptername{}
      \renewcommand\printchapternum{\null\hfill\feline@chm[2.5cm]\par}
      \renewcommand\afterchapternum{\par\vskip\midchapskip}
      \renewcommand\printchaptertitle[1]{\chaptitlefont\raggedleft ##1\par}
    }
    \makeatother
    \chapterstyle{daleif1}
```

[image]

I would like to have the red box in the top left hand corner. I have been trying for hours without any results...

Does anyone can help me please ?

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! daleif is a regular here, so I guess he'll be helping you soon.

Comment: Just remove the `\null\hfill` from `printchapternum`, which pushes it over to the right.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

The only change was in

```
 \renewcommand\printchapternum{\null\hfill\feline@chm[2.5cm]\par}
```

deleting the `\null\hfill`.

The code:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{color,calc,graphicx,soul,fourier}
\usepackage{lipsum}

    \definecolor{nicered}{rgb}{.647,.129,.149}
    \makeatletter
    \newlength\dlf@normtxtw
    \setlength\dlf@normtxtw{\textwidth}
    \def\myhelvetfont{\def\sfdefault{mdput}}
    \newsavebox{\feline@chapter}
    \newcommand\feline@chapter@marker[1][4cm]{%
      \sbox\feline@chapter{%
        \resizebox{!}{#1}{\fboxsep=1pt%
          \colorbox{nicered}{\color{white}\bfseries\sffamily\thechapter}%
        }}%
      \rotatebox{90}{%
        \resizebox{%
          \heightof{\usebox{\feline@chapter}}+\depthof{\usebox{\feline@chapter}}}%
        {!}{\scshape\so\@chapapp}}\quad%
      \raisebox{\depthof{\usebox{\feline@chapter}}}{\usebox{\feline@chapter}}%
    }
    \newcommand\feline@chm[1][4cm]{%
      \sbox\feline@chapter{\feline@chapter@marker[#1]}%
      \makebox[0pt][l]{% aka \rlap
        \makebox[1cm][r]{\usebox\feline@chapter}%
      }}
    \makechapterstyle{daleif1}{
      \renewcommand\chapnamefont{\normalfont\Large\scshape\raggedleft\so}
      \renewcommand\chaptitlefont{\normalfont\huge\bfseries\scshape\color{nicered}}
      \renewcommand\chapternamenum{}
      \renewcommand\printchaptername{}
      \renewcommand\printchapternum{\feline@chm[2.5cm]\par}
      \renewcommand\afterchapternum{\par\vskip\midchapskip}
      \renewcommand\printchaptertitle[1]{\chaptitlefont\raggedleft ##1\par}
    }
    \makeatother
    \chapterstyle{daleif1}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test chapter}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

In a comment it was requested to move the heading upwards, so the upper border of the red box coincides with the upper border of the page; this can be made by adding

```
\setlength\beforechapskip{-135pt}
```

to the definition of the theme, and perhaps also

```
\renewcommand*\printchapternonum{\phantom{\feline@chm[2.5cm]}\par}
```

so titles for unnumbered chapters won't start too high. A complete example:

```
 \documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{color,calc,graphicx,soul,fourier}
\usepackage{lipsum}

    \definecolor{nicered}{rgb}{.647,.129,.149}
    \makeatletter
    \newlength\dlf@normtxtw
    \setlength\dlf@normtxtw{\textwidth}
    \def\myhelvetfont{\def\sfdefault{mdput}}
    \newsavebox{\feline@chapter}
    \newcommand\feline@chapter@marker[1][4cm]{%
      \sbox\feline@chapter{%
        \resizebox{!}{#1}{\fboxsep=1pt%
          \colorbox{nicered}{\color{white}\bfseries\sffamily\thechapter}%
        }}%
      \rotatebox{90}{%
        \resizebox{%
          \heightof{\usebox{\feline@chapter}}+\depthof{\usebox{\feline@chapter}}}%
        {!}{\scshape\so\@chapapp}}\quad%
      \raisebox{\depthof{\usebox{\feline@chapter}}}{\usebox{\feline@chapter}}%
    }
    \newcommand\feline@chm[1][4cm]{%
      \sbox\feline@chapter{\feline@chapter@marker[#1]}%
      \makebox[0pt][l]{% aka \rlap
        \makebox[1cm][r]{\usebox\feline@chapter}%
      }}
    \makechapterstyle{daleif1}{
      \renewcommand\chapnamefont{\normalfont\Large\scshape\raggedleft\so}
      \renewcommand\chaptitlefont{\normalfont\huge\bfseries\scshape\color{nicered}}
      \renewcommand\chapternamenum{}
      \renewcommand\printchaptername{}
      \setlength\beforechapskip{-135pt}
      \renewcommand\printchapternum{\feline@chm[2.5cm]\par}
      \renewcommand*\printchapternonum{\phantom{\feline@chm[2.5cm]}\par}%
      \renewcommand\afterchapternum{\par\vskip\midchapskip}
      \renewcommand\printchaptertitle[1]{\chaptitlefont\raggedleft ##1\par}
    }
    \makeatother
    \chapterstyle{daleif1}

\begin{document}

\chapter*{Test unnumbered chapter}
\lipsum[2]
\chapter{Test numbered chapter}
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Oh my God, it works !

However, I would like to have the same thing with a left, right,bottom, and top margin of 2 cm.

Comment: @TexisHard I don't understand what do you mean with "margin" in your comment. Please clearly explain what dimensions should be 2cm.

Comment: How could I get the top red-box border in contact with the top of the blank sheet ?

Comment: @TexisHard So, you want to shift everything (the red box and the title) upwards, so the upper border of the red box touches the upper border of the physical page?

Comment: Correct !! Thats it!

Comment: @TexisHard Add `\setlength\beforechapskip{-135pt}` in the definition of `daleif1`. Let me know if this is what you wanted.

Comment: Sorry, but where is the definition of daleif1 in the code please ?

Comment: @TexisHard when you say  `\makechapterstyle{daleif1}{...}` You can place the line of code I gave right after `\renewcommand\printchapternum{\feline@chm[2.5cm]\par}` in the code of my answer.

Comment: @TexisHard You're welcome! Perhaps you also want to add `\renewcommand*\printchapternonum{\phantom{\feline@chm[2.5cm]}\par}`
so the title for unnumbered chapters won't start too high.

Comment: @TexisHard And, by the way, don't forget that after a sensible wait you can accept an answer that you consider solved your problem by clicking the checkmark to its left. In case of doubt, please see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852/3954).

Comment: This solution is very relevant for people using Daleif1 theme and who want to keep their topmargin for the next pages of their document.